# Spring CachingConnectionFactory NOT closing shared MQQueueConnection during Tomcat shutdown on Linux host

Tags: linux, tomcat, spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a `spring-integration 4.0.x` based application which makes connections to a Websphere MQ manager for producing/consuming JMS messages. The application is currently deployed on a `Tomcat 7.0.x` container which, when running on a Windows host, the application stops as expected when the container is shutdown but, when running on a RH6 Linux host, the application fails to stop as expected when the container is shutdown.

Looking at trace level logging during the Linux based shutdown, I can see that the application gets stuck when trying to close JMS connections to the Websphere MQ queues:

```
15:24:30.628 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'cachingConnectionFactory'
15:24:30.628 [localhost-startStop-2] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Closing shared JMS Connection: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection@13909638
```

The application then remains at this point for about 15 minutes until the following then gets logged:

```
15:40:24.247 [task-scheduler-1] TRACE org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Logical close of cached JMS Session failed - discarding it
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: MQJMS1024: session closed
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.checkSessionOpen(MQSession.java:2629) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-6.0.2.3.jar:6.0.2.3 - j600-203-080121  ]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.getTransacted(MQSession.java:1385) ~[com.ibm.mqjms-6.0.2.3.jar:6.0.2.3 - j600-203-080121  ]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.logicalClose(CachingConnectionFactory.java:457) ~[spring-jms-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:309) [spring-jms-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.close(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.closeSession(JmsUtils.java:108) [spring-jms-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:497) [spring-jms-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:761) [spring-jms-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsDestinationPollingSource.doReceiveJmsMessage(JmsDestinationPollingSource.java:122) [spring-integration-jms-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsDestinationPollingSource.receive(JmsDestinationPollingSource.java:96) [spring-integration-jms-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:144) [spring-integration-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:192) [spring-integration-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55) [spring-integration-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149) [spring-integration-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146) [spring-integration-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298) [spring-integration-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52) [spring-integration-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49) [spring-integration-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:292) [spring-integration-core-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) [spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81) [spring-context-4.0.8.RELEASE.jar:4.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_25]
15:40:24.257 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Closing cached Session: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSession@6d33d604
15:40:24.258 [task-scheduler-1] DEBUG org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter - Poll interrupted - during stop()? : MQJMS1024: session closed; nested exception is javax.jms.IllegalStateException: MQJMS1024: session closed
```

My application runs using the following stack:

```
java 8

com.ibm:com.ibm.mq:6.0.2.3
com.ibm:com.ibm.mqjms:6.0.2.3
javax.jms:jms:1.1
org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.0.1.RELEASE
org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:4.0.4.RELEASE
```

My application's JMS config is shown here:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class JmsConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Properties jndiProperties;
    
    private ConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {
        
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
        
        try {
            MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (MQQueueConnectionFactory)
                ctx.lookup("jms/service/SERVICE_QCF");
        
            return connectionFactory;
            
        } finally {
            ctx.close();
        }   
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() throws NamingException {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory());
        connectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(false);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
}
```

My application's Integration config is partially shown here:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow requestFlow() {
    
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from("request.ch")
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(cachingConnectionFactory)
                    .destination("REQUEST_QUEUE")).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow responseFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
                   .from(Jms.inboundAdapter(cachingConnectionFactory).destination(
                        "RESPONSE_QUEUE"),
                        c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000).maxMessagesPerPoll(10)))
                  .channel("response.ch")
                .get();
    }

    ...
}
```

How can I ensure that connections to the MQ manager's queues are properly closed upon the application stopping/closing down?

Thanks in advance,
PM

Comment: As a test, I have removed the `CachingConnectionFactory` bean altogether and passed the `MQConnectionFactory` bean directly to the integration flow's `JMS inbound/outbound Adapter`s. When I do this, the application stops properly both in Windows and Linux hosts. The issue seems to be with the `CachingConnectionFactory`. At the moment, I am not entirely sure what the difference is (performance-wise) between using one `ConnectionFactory` or the other. Will look at differences and report back...

Comment: You're using an incredibly old version of the MQ Java client, 6.0.2.3 - which isn't even supported by IBM anymore. Have you considered using something newer like the 7.5.0.5 client? Much more up to date, with many fixes and enhancements in. Also worth noting that Java 8 isn't supported by any version of MQ Java client either, newest which is supported is Java 7.

Comment: IBM supply their 7.5 clients free of charge here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032744

Comment: Hello @TimMcCormick, I think you are spot on. Tried the application out with `MQ client jars version 7.0.1.3` and with these, the application stops quickly as it should on both Windows and Linux hosts. The reason I was using v6 MQ client jars was because a) Our legacy applications all run and worked using v6 MQ client jars, b) Our MQ managers are all v6 (I am told). I imagine it is not necessarily a problem to use v7 MQ clients against v6 MQ managers? Also, do you know when there is likely to be a Java 8 supported MQ client? Finally, post your solution as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer...

You're using an incredibly old version of the MQ Java client, 6.0.2.3 - which isn't even supported by IBM anymore. Have you considered using something newer like the 7.5.0.5 client? Much more up to date, with many fixes and enhancements in. Also worth noting that Java 8 isn't supported by any version of MQ Java client either, newest which is supported is Java 7.

IBM supply their 7.5 clients free of charge here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24032744

The design of MQ is such that all versions of client can work with all versions of queue manager. So it certainly isn't a problem to use a 7.5 client with a 6.0 queue manager, or any other combination.

I'm sure IBM will announce support for Java 8 with IBM MQ at some point, but there's nothing public I'm aware of with any dates. You can request support (and functional enhancements) here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Might be worth submitting an RFE for Java 8 on IBM MQ in your case. (Note: it's still called WebSphere MQ on the RFE pages)

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem stopping Camel route consuming IBM MQ with Spring CachingConnectionFactory in OSGi container (Karaf).
The solution was setting:

```
cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(false);
```

If that doesn't help, try to call:

```
cachingConnectionFactory.resetConnection();
```

from some kind of your application's destroying method.